# Como enviar de forma correcta un comentario (input) a la base de datos haciendo uso de PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando una parte en mi pagina que sirva para enviar comentarios. Ya realice el form con los input correspondientes. Que serian los siguientes:

```
<form action="comments.php" method="POST">
    <div class="BoxComments">  
            <input class="text" type="text" actionid="username"placeholder="Name" name="nombreC">
        <br>
        <br>
            <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailC">
        <br>
        <br>
            <input  class="BoxComment" id="BoxComment2"type="form" placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></input>
        <br>
            <button  class ="ButtonComments" name="send" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Realice el siguiente codigo en PHP pero no se logra enviar. Adjunto el codigo:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["send"])){

    include ("../../connect.php");
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phplogin");
    $nameC = !empty($_POST['nameC']) ? $_POST['nameC'] : NULL; //Se define la variable utilizando los name de los input
    $emailC = !empty($_POST['emailC']) ? $_POST['emailC'] : NULL;
    $comment = !empty($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : NULL; 

    $sql="INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')"; //Sentencia SQL

    $eject=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); //Se ejecuta la sentencia

    if(!$eject){ // Aviso de ejecucion
        echo"Fallo al enviar";
    }else{
        echo"Enviado con exito";

    }
}
    
   // echo "{$nombreC}, {$comment}";

?>
```

Me dice fallo al enviar

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Benito. Ahi estaba el problema

Comment: Te lo dejo como respuesta para que se vea más claro :)

Comment: Tengo una pregunta nueva, mysqli_query esta esperando dos argumentos, Como se ve en el codigo yo le pase un solo argumento, Que le deberia pasar de segundo argumento?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir esa parte

Comment: En el `$_POST` tienes que usar lo que hayas escrito en el `name` de los elementos. Aquí `$_POST['nameC']` no recuperarás el valor porque el input se llama `nombreC`, así que debes cambiarlo por `$_POST['nomnreC']`, aparte de eso faltan algunos controles en tu código y por eso no sabes lo que ocurre. En una consulta SQL puede haber varios tipos de errores y tu tarea como programador es controlarlos y no lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Que palabra reservada tendria que utilizar para controlar los errores? Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Corregi eso y sigue saliendo. Que deberia hacer?

Answer (score 1):

En las últimas versiones de php el tag para abrir php es `<?php`. Sin eso no funcionará lo que haya dentro.

En cuanto a la query:  `$eject=mysqli_query($sql);`
[mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) requiere que el primer parámetro sea la [conexión](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) a la base de datos, que es lo que obtienes cuando haces `$conn = mysqli_connect("blablabla");`

Comment: Yo no tengo el $conn, Es necesario? 

Creia que la conexion simplemente era usar un include y el file donde tengo la conexion mysql.

Comment: `mysql_query` NECESITA la conexión para funcionar. Supongo que en ese include que haces debe haber una conexión... no? Pues tienes que pasársela al `mysql_query`o no va a funcionar, porque ese método no sabe cuál es tu conexión si tú no se lo indicas.

Comment: Ya no me saltan errores. Pero de todas formas no me lo envia. Editare el codigo para ver si podes ver el problema

Answer (score -1):

Estas validando que exista la variable send, pero no la estas enviando en tu form, es decir, en tu form el post solo envía el valor de tus input's pero no envía el valor de tus buttons. Si quieres que se mande el valor del button, deberías cambiarlo a un input de tipo submit:

```
<form action="comments.php" method="POST">
<div class="BoxComments">  
        <input class="text" type="text" actionid="username"placeholder="Name" name="nombreC">
    <br>
    <br>
        <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailC">
    <br>
    <br>
        <input  class="BoxComment" id="BoxComment2"type="form" placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></input>
    <br>
    <input class="ButtonComments" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
```

Asi recibirías en tu post el valor de "send" y entraría en tu if

Comment: Un `if` con `isset()` entrará igual aunque la variable esté vacía, si usase `empty()` no.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste, pero aun asi me dice "Fallo al enviar"